# Issue creation and commenting via email in Redmine

Tags: email, redmine

I'm a Redmine user and administrator. I want to configure Redmine to allow issue creation and commenting via email. I need to configure it in such a way that it reads emails from standard input. (not from imap, pop3, or email server) Can anyone please suggest a suitable way and required code segment for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redmine does have `rake`tasks to query `pop3` and `imap` mail accounts.

See [Redmine wiki](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails)